# PIC16F877 Using External Crystal

Tags: pic, c, crystal

I am working on a digital clock project. I'm using PIC 16F877 microcontroller and 4 MHz external crystal. I finished the project and I have drawn the PCB. Before I upload the code to the MC I'm wondering if there is anything I need to add to the code. Perhaps something about crystal or any configuration codes. Here you can see the first part of the code where I defined the variables and fuses. Is there anything else I should include?

[image]

Comment: You need to post code as text, not as (incomplete) pictures of text.

Comment: Please ask questions about coding in a Stack Exchange about programming. This one is about hardware.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Microcontroller programming is explicitly on-topic here, always has been. Particularly if the question is regarding hardware peripherals, oscillators and the like. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for that link. I'll have you note that software is mentioned only in the "it is not about …" section.

Comment: @Linefollow ... I wonder if you have a particular reason for your unconventional C layout?  Although there are many conventions, as far as I know they all suggest indenting within every if/loop/etc as being the easiest to read.  Perhaps you'll find the [Harvard CS50 Styleguide](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/style/c/) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - you will need to set #fuses to "XT" (external crystal) instead of "HS" to use a 4MHz crystal oscillator.